# Best way to dismiss a view controller?

Tags: swift

What is the best way to dismiss a view controller?

I would like to implement code so I can dismiss the view controller programmatically by a button action instead of using the Back button on the navigation bar.

Comment: Apple's documentation on Presenting a View Controller & Dismiss
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sh_Khan has hit the nail on the head but if you are presenting it modally you should also include a `dismiss`.

Example:

```
@IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This will `pop` the top view controller and `dismiss` the view controller if it was presented modally.

Comment: @Sh_Khan hahaha :D

Comment: You should not call both. Call one or the other depending on how the view controller is originally displayed.

Comment: @rmaddy is wrong as it doesn’t work for me using only one of them I have to put both in before it works at all

Comment: @Jansenbase Then something else is going on because you never need to call both to dismiss a view controller. If a view controller was pushed onto a nav controller, you call `popViewController`. If the view controller was presented, then you call `dismiss`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```